# Plotting multiple lines in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(Day =c(rep(2,9),rep(5,9),rep(9,9)),Treat = 
rep(c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),3), Length = 
c(2,4,3,5,3,3,8,3,7,3,6,7,4,7,8,8,8,8,10,7,5,7,8,9,19,20,12), Width = 
seq(1,27,1))
head(data)
```

I'd like to create two line graphs in ggplot, with "Day" on the X axis and either "Length" or "Width" on the Y. On both graphs, I'd like separate lines for the means of each "Treat", with SE bars at each point.

I've tried getting my data into long format:

```
data_long <- melt(data, c(1,2), c(3,4))
```

Is there an efficient way to coerce ggplot into calculating the proper summary statistics and then plot by group? I have tried with "Day" as both an integer and a factor, and by melting the original dataset separately for "length" and "width". Any help much appreciated!

Comment: That's not how SO works (give me the code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use the `summarySE()` defined [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Summarizing_data/) for error bars, I hope the below produces what you were looking for.

First the summary function:

```
summarySE <- function(data=NULL, measurevar, groupvars=NULL, na.rm=FALSE,
                      conf.interval=.95, .drop=TRUE) {
  library(plyr)

  # New version of length which can handle NA's: if na.rm==T, don't count them
  length2 <- function (x, na.rm=FALSE) {
    if (na.rm) sum(!is.na(x))
    else       length(x)
  }

  # This does the summary. For each group's data frame, return a vector with
  # N, mean, and sd
  datac <- ddply(data, groupvars, .drop=.drop,
                 .fun = function(xx, col) {
                   c(N    = length2(xx[[col]], na.rm=na.rm),
                     mean = mean   (xx[[col]], na.rm=na.rm),
                     sd   = sd     (xx[[col]], na.rm=na.rm)
                   )
                 },
                 measurevar
  )

  # Rename the "mean" column    
  datac <- rename(datac, c("mean" = measurevar))

  datac$se <- datac$sd / sqrt(datac$N)  # Calculate standard error of the mean

  # Confidence interval multiplier for standard error
  # Calculate t-statistic for confidence interval: 
  # e.g., if conf.interval is .95, use .975 (above/below), and use df=N-1
  ciMult <- qt(conf.interval/2 + .5, datac$N-1)
  datac$ci <- datac$se * ciMult

  return(datac)
}
```

Then plugging your data in.

```
data <- data.frame(Day =c(rep(2,9),rep(5,9),rep(9,9)),Treat = 
rep(c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),3), Length = 
c(2,4,3,5,3,3,8,3,7,3,6,7,4,7,8,8,8,8,10,7,5,7,8,9,19,20,12), Width = 
seq(1,27,1))
summarized <- summarySE(data, measurevar="Length", groupvars=c("Treat", "Day"))
summarized
```

Then the ggplot itself.

```
ggplot(summarized, aes(x=Day, y=Length, colour=Treat)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Length-se, ymax=Length+se), width=.1) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Brilliant - I need to tweak the aesthetics, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped--consider hitting the accept button if it solved your problem, or feel free to pursue a better solution :) And welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a much simpler solution that helps prevent overlap while graphing, and it accounts for the more standard 95% confidence interval in the error bars:

```
require(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  Day = c(rep(2,9),rep(5,9),rep(9,9)),
  Treat = rep(c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),3), 
  Length = c(2,4,3,5,3,3,8,3,7,3,6,7,4,7,8,8,8,8,10,7,5,7,8,9,19,20,12),
  Width = seq(1,27,1))

#Use aggregate function to find mean "Length" based on "Treat" and "Day"
plotDf <- aggregate(Length ~ Treat + Day, mean, na.rm=TRUE, data=df)

#Create function that uses 95% confidence interval to make SE bars
#Note: you can adjust CI by removing/replacing '1.96*' as needed.
find_se <- function(x) 1.96*sd(x,na.rm=TRUE)/sqrt(length(x))

#Use aggregate function to calculate SEs based on "Treat" and "Day"
plotDf$SE <- setNames(
  aggregate(Length ~ Treat + Day,find_se, data=df)[,"Length"],"SE")

#Plot (uses position_dodge to avoid overlap)
pd <- position_dodge(.2)
ggplot(data=plotDf, aes(x=Day,y=Length,colour=Treat)) +
       geom_line(position=pd) +
       geom_point(position=pd) +
       geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Length-SE, ymax=Length+SE),
                     width=.3, position=pd)
```

Graphical output:

[image: graphical output from the code in the question]